# iOS how to correctly remove observer

Tags: ios

Im trying to figure out how to remove the following observer:

```
[self.messageInputView.textView addObserver:self
                                 forKeyPath:@"contentSize"
                                    options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew
                                    context:nil];
```

I want to clean it in my dealloc method.

I've tried:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
```

But this does not seem to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're adding a key-value observer, which is different than an `NSNotification` observer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you didn't add yourself as an observer on the NSNotificationCenter.  Try:
`[self.messageInputView.textView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"]`

Answer (score 0):

try this `[self.messageInputView.textView removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize" context:nil];`

Answer (score 0):

For remove an observer use this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentSize"];
```

And you need to put this code in your ViewDidUnload method of your controller